# What is the point of the make_transform_iterator as the second parameter in thrust::reduce algorithm?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, thrust

The code is as follows:

```
thrust::reduce(thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), square()),
                  thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.end(),   square()));
```

Taken from transform_iterator example [here](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1transform__iterator.html). Specifically, isn't it redundant to use the following as the second iterator?

```
thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.end(), square())
```

Why not just use the following in its place?

```
 thrust::reduce(thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), square()),
                  v.end());
```

I suppose in this particular example, since `thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), square())` does not produce an iterator that is of different size than `v`, my updated code would do the same thing as the original, is that correct?

**EDIT**
My only guess is that it's to make sure both iterators are of the same type? All I found to confirm my suspicion on this was the following text in that documentation "the transform functor (namely square_root and square) inherits from thrust::unary_function. Inheriting from thrust::unary_function ensures that a functor is a valid AdaptableUnaryFunction and provides all the necessary typedef declarations." Although, I think this specifically is referring to the functor itself.

**UPDATE**
See Robert Crovella's comment for answer.

Comment: The iterators here are used to mark the beginning and ending of a specific sequence. v.end does not mark the end of the sequence that the transform iterator marks the start of.

Comment: Oh, I don't know why I was struggling to grasp that. I guess the key word being "specific" sequence. It has to point to the same place in memory. `v.end()` is not the same end position in memory as the end position of the iterator made by `thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), square())`. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use `thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), square()) + v.size()`. It may look more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterators here are used to mark the beginning and ending of a specific sequence. `v.end()` does not mark the end of the sequence that the transform iterator here:

```
thrust::reduce(thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), square()),
              v.end());
```

marks the start of.

Some other constructs here might have a better appearance (beauty is in the eye of the beholder), such as:

```
auto my_iter = thrust::make_transform_iterator(v.begin(), square());
thrust::reduce(my_iter, my_iter+v.size());
```